# fast drawing Bitmaps, Directshow source filter

Tags: .net, windows, graphics, directx, directshow

I need a method to render Bitmaps very fast. I use a Directshow filter graph for webcam and video images, it works great, but I need to draw other images, like diagrams, animations etc..
I can use Directshow for this purpose too, but it seems to me too difficult for this simple task. My questions:
- What is the fastest, simplest, most conventional way to draw bitmaps on Windows?
- Is there any Directshow source filter to render in memory bitmaps?

Comment: Are you only interested in DirectX solutions, or are you willing to call native APIs as well?

Comment: I'm interested in everything what solve my problem (eg. OpenGL too).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you are on a newer machine.

You could also look into using Direct3D for 2D rendering if you are on an older machine.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Direct3D, but: my bitmaps always change (this is an animation), so I need to create new textures for every frame, my experience shows it is inefficient (maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: I'll try Direct2D eventually, because I want compatibility with WinXP.

Comment: Don't quote me but I think direct2D is not available on windows XP

Comment: However you are creating the textures I would think you could do it within DirectX. If you have them all rendered ahead of time you can load them to have them ready to use.